# Getting Exception class not found on PDO method

Tags: php, sql, class, autoload

I'm getting an unexpected exception. When I Update data like this:

```
try {
  $restaurantUpd = new Restaurant();
  $restaurantUpd->updateRestaurant(array( 'restaurant_name' => Input::get('restaurant_name'),
                                          'restaurant_location' => Input::get('restaurant_location'),
                                          'restaurant_contact_email' => Input::get('restaurant_contact_email')
                                        ), $_GET['edit']);
  //ok
} catch(Exception $e) {
  die($e->getMessage());
}
```

It returns this error:
`Warning: require_once(classes/Exeption.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\admintest\core\init.php on line 32`

But the strange thing is I have no `Exeption.php` class? Also, the line 32 refers to my autoload:

```
/*
* Autoload function for classes
*/
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    require_once 'classes/' . $class . '.php';
});
```

My update method in Restaurant class is like this...

```
public function updateRestaurant($fields = array(), $id = null) {
    if (!$this->_db->update('rt_restaurant', $id, $fields, false)) {
        throw new Exeption('There was a problem updating');
    }
}
```

ANd the update method from DB class is PDO prepare, execute, fetch

Any guidance?

Comment: `Exeption` suggests there may be a typo

Comment: spl_autoload_register try to require a file if that CLASS is not found, in your program, it try to search Exception Class which is called in your CATCH, probably you are using old version of PHP. Please tell your php version and check if it has Exception class...

Comment: My php version id up to date... PHP Version 5.4.22

Comment: Do a global lookup for `Exeption.php`; you almost certainly have a typo somewhere. `Exception.php` is what you want. (Note the `c`.)

Comment: wow................ just edited my question to give more info and now i see my typo ... sorry guys,, when its on stack overflow its seems more clear (it was in the class method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a typo in the class method

```
public function updateRestaurant($fields = array(), $id = null) {
    if (!$this->_db->update('rt_restaurant', $id, $fields, false)) {
        throw new Exeption('There was a problem updating');
    }
}
```

Also... the exception whas thrown because there was a error in de DB method I was selecting WHERE id = $ID

but in MySQL it was not called id but rest_id.

Answer (score 0):

You have spelling mistake
`Exeption` will be `Exception` in this line

```
throw new Exeption('There was a problem updating');
```

If not that works:

Try this:

```
} catch(\Exception $e) {
```

and

```
throw new \Exception('There was a problem updating');
```

From manual
`Prefixing a name with \ will specify that the name is required from the global space even in the context of the namespace.`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.fallback.php

Comment: What is at top of your file? any namespace or use statement?